# Reload datatable without reloading page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net

How do I reload the datatable without reloading the entire page? I want it to get the new values from "AllSales". I am also using jquery plugin "datatable" for my table.

```
   $("#SalesTable").dataTable();
```

Here is my table :

```
<table id="SalesTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <% {
                                foreach (var item in AllSales)
                                {
                                   %>
                                   <tr>
                                     <td><%=item.Date %></td>
                                     <td><%=item.Email%> </td>
                                   </tr>
                                <%}
                            }
                         %>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Do you want the reload to occur at a set time or on an event?

Comment: @KG Christensen: It will be every time I get a new sale so on an event.

Comment: Okay, but where does the sale come from? What kind of page is it you're making? Is it supposed to monitor "all sales"?

Comment: I have a background thread that counts the sales in my database, and if the counter have increased from the last saved value, then we have a sale. This page is just showing the sales, and if there is a new sale, i want it to be shown as well without reloading the page.

Comment: If you have something running in the background checking for updates, isn't it as simple as calling the function that builds the datatables again?

Comment: Exactly, and the function that builds my datatable is the code above, and this is what i am asking, how do i make it run again without loading the page .

Comment: Do a call from the running "thread" to the orginal function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the data using ajax, throw it into an object and dynamically change the content of your datatable based on the object.  It's been years since I've used any .net languages, so I can't write you an example in asp.

```
<html>
<tbody id='datatable'>
</tbody>
</html>

var tbodyData;
var post = $.ajax({
 url: "someurl.asp",
 type: "POST",
 data: {"some data"},
 success: function() {
  var object = post.responseText;
  object.parseJSON();
  for (data in object) {
   tbodyData += "<tr><td>" + object[data] + "</td></tr>\n";
  }
  $("datatable").html(tbodyData);
 }
});
```

Something like that should do it.